# How to get the latest date time record in an sql query with a where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables : `RO_LAMEL_DATA` and `RO_MAIN_TABLE`. `RO_MAIN_TABLE` includes all the serial numbers (`serial_nr`) for the productions which have a record key (`record_key`). `RO_LAMEL_DATA` has several records (on the same day) for each record key such as machine status (`machine_status`) with a date time value (`pr_date_time`). I want to get the latest machine status of one production. For this I do:

```
select a.machine_status
from ro_lamel_Data a inner join (
    select record_key, max(pr_date_time) as MaxDate
    from ro_lamel_Data
    group by record_key
) ro_main_table on (a.record_key = ro_main_table.record_key) and a.pr_date_time = MaxDate
where a.record_key =(
    select record_key from ro_main_table where serial_nr = 'Y39489');
```

However I get the error:

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need something like

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT machine_status, 
                     record_key,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY record_key 
                                        ORDER BY pr_date_time DESC) rn
              FROM ro_lamel_Data )
SELECT cte.record_key, cte.machine_status last_status
FROM cte 
JOIN ro_main_table ON cte.record_key = ro_main_table.record_key
WHERE rn = 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=539cff53cad23dd631cdf9b0f9406e5a)

Comment: What is cte and rn in this case?

Comment: @Eda `cte` is Common Table Expression alias. `rn` is column alias.

Comment: After you edited, now it says: "CTE"."RECORD_KEY": invalid identifier, Error at Line: 7, what can I do?

Comment: @Eda Corrected. Fiddle added.

Comment: Great, it complies, but instead of having the list of all record keys, I just want to have one specific which is the same as `record_key` of a `serial_nr` (e.g. 'Y12134') from `ro_main_table`. Is this possible?

Comment: @Eda Nothing prevents to add WHERE clause(s) with according condition(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row, the use `order by` and `fetch first`:

```
select ld.machine_status
from ro_lamel_Data ld join
     ro_main_table mt
     using (record_key)
where mt.serial_nr = 'Y39489'
order by ld.pr_ate_time desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```